# Is there any way how I can use Mathematica in Introduction Logic course?

Tags: logic, wolfram-alpha

I am very new comer to Wolfram Mathematica software tool and I am interesting is there any way how I can apply this tool for Introductory Logic course. I am participating at the course on 'coursera' it is promising to be math intensive, we are going to employ a set theory, expressions manipulation techniques (similar to algebra, but in logic context) . Is it make any sense to apply such powerful tool for that kind of task or I over complicate a task? From my perspective I am looking for ways to increase my understanding of the subject.

Any suggestions or advice are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.
Nick

Comment: [mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) may be a better suited site for this question

Comment: It depends on what topics course covers. What is the course name?

Comment: Introduction to Logic

Comment: I took this course. It uses fitch-style proof system. This course provides its own software for doing fitch-style proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Mathematica is in my opinion the strongest mathematical computation language, but it has some downsides. For logical arguments, which are usually somewhat long, it's time-consuming to encode it to input it for Mathematica to simplify/evaluate, but once you get used to it, it's easier. Here are some commands you can use;

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LogicAndBooleanAlgebra.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiableQ.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Implies.html